# Make the width of text in a tcb the same as ```\textwidth```

Tags: tcolorbox

In tcolorboxes, the text is normally narrower than `\textwidth` because the text box has a frame and some margin. After looking at the picture on "quick reference" of the tcolorbox documentation, I got a solution, and that is to set the keys `right`, `left`, `leftrule` and `rightrule` to `0pt`. However the result is very ugly and I receive errors because LaTeX thinks the `0pt`s are inappropriate.

How to meet this requirement in a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `oversize` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{tcolorbox}[oversize]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]